# How to know if an event is created in Google Calendar with GAS?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I want to know if there's the possibiliy to know when an event in google calendar is created, I just have found how to create an event and take its info to create another I want to send the info of the event to a spreadsheed or any document

I just got this..

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('Evento de prueba',
      new Date('December 20 2014 10:00:00 AM -6'),
      new Date('December 20 2014 10:30:00 AM -6'),
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().
        onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY]),
       { location: 'Tacos'});
     Logger.log('EventSeriesID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
     if (eventSeries.getTitle() == 'Evento de prueba'){
         var calendarId2 = 'primary';
         var event = CalendarApp.createEvent(eventSeries.getTitle(), eventSeries.getDateCreated(), new Date(eventSeries.getDateCreated() + 2),
         {location : eventSeries.getLocation()});
     }
}
```

Comment: What data do you want to put into your spreadsheet from this calendar event ?

Comment: Title, description, Email from the person who created the event and after feed the doc with this information, send the doc to my gmail and then to a database and I dont know if that is possible.

Comment: You could be sent an email, when that function runs.  Or do you want something different?  It depends on how you want to "know" when the event is created.

Comment: For example, any user inside my domain creates an Event let's suppose that he/she chose the event to be in color red, with any "title" and any description, I want to know The Description, the title, the color and the user's email who created the event and send that information to a doc which is gonna be in my Email or another person email from my domain. @SandyGood

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this is with a stand alone Apps Script that has a time driven trigger that checks your calender at some time interval.  In the Apps Script code editor, click the RESOURCES menu, choose CURRENT PROJECTS TRIGGERS, and add a trigger.  That will cause the function to run at whatever time interval you set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want this way or other way, but you can try for the following code.

```
function createEvent() {
  try{
     var calendarId = 'primary';
     var eventSeries = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar().createEventSeries('My Events',
      new Date('December 20 2014 12:00:00 PM'),
      new Date('December 20 2014 03:30:00 PM'),
        CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addWeeklyRule().onlyOnWeekdays([CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY]),
       { location: 'Tacos'});
     Logger.log('EventSeriesID: ' + eventSeries.getId());
     if (eventSeries.getTitle() == 'My Events'){
         var calendarId2 = 'primary';
         var event = CalendarApp.createEvent(eventSeries.getTitle(), eventSeries.getDateCreated(), new Date(eventSeries.getDateCreated() + 2),
         {location : eventSeries.getLocation()});

         var ss_id = logEventData(event);
       Logger.log(ss_id);
         sendMail(ss_id);
     }
  }catch(error){
    Logger.log(error.message); 
  }
}

function logEventData(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('calender-events-logs');
  var eventDetails = [];

  eventDetails.push(event.getTitle());
  eventDetails.push(event.getDescription());
  eventDetails.push(event.getCreators()[0]);

  //You can get number of other details here if you want to.

  ss.appendRow(eventDetails);

  return ss.getId();
}

function sendMail(ss_id) {
  var emailTo = 'Put your email id here';
  var subject = 'Test';
  var body = 'Test';

  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(ss_id).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attachment = {fileName:'CalendarEventLogs.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, body, {attachments:[attachment]});
  //MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);

  // Delete the dummy spreadsheet
  deleteDummySheet(ss_id);
}

function deleteDummySheet(ss_id) {
  DocsList.getFileById(ss_id).setTrashed(true);
}
```

Comment: That was almost what I want, I think your code is Ok but is stadarized, because I'm not getting any Email and, this same way, how can works if insted of me creating the event it was an event created by someone else within my domain?

Comment: Are you not getting any emails using my code? And, sorry but I didn't get your question about "event created by others". Can you please explain again if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes, im not getting any Email with your Code, I think that im missing Something I fiil te "emailTo" variable with my Email, and Subject, but I don't know.. mayb is because I don't have any SpreadSheet ID, or at least I don't know how to get it, and the thing of Events created by other is... if someone inside my domain of emails create an event with an especific title or color, or location then send the description, title, email to the spreadSheet, I don't know if i explained myself well?.

Comment: It is working perfectly for me. Yes in sendMail() function, you need to put your email id or anyone's id and also you need to put the spreadsheet id. But, I would still recommend to check error logs after running this script as I have put this code in try and catch block, so you will see if there is any error. You can check logs by pressing ctrl+enter keys.

Comment: Regarding your events created by others, you will have to follow other approach, i.e create a dummy spreadsheet records the data and send it to required email address, and delete that spreadsheet.

Comment: I have edited above code so even if it runs by other user, it will send you the pdf file with log data. I guess, this is what you wanted, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, thats almost all what I wanted in functionality but I have to know if I can make a rule or a trigger that makes the code happen, I mean instead of me creating the Event, when other user creates an Event with specific parameters I mean like an specific Title, it triggers the code, you know what I mean?